# Строковые массивы с++

Tags: c++

Вывести те слова, в которых буква «а» повторяется дважды.
Сколько раз уже делал, ничего не получается, уже отчаялся. Код представлен ниже.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    char slovo1[100];
    char slovo2[100];
    char slovo3[100];
    char slovo4[100];
    char slovo5[100];
    char slovo6[100];
    //char a[33] = { 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','\0'};
    char a[2] = { 'a','\0' };
    int i, n,k = 0;

    cout << "Введите первое слово - ";
    cin >> slovo1;
    cout << "Введите следующее слово  - ";
    cin >> slovo2;
    cout << "Введите следующее слово  - ";
    cin >> slovo3;
    cout << "Введите следующее слово  - ";
    cin >> slovo4;
    cout << "Введите следующее слово  - ";
    cin >> slovo5;
    n = strlen(slovo1);

    for (i=0; i < n; i++);
    {

        if (slovo1[i] == a[0])
        {
            k++;
            if (k == 2)
            {
                cout << "Слова - " << slovo1;
            }
            else if (k != 2)
            {
                cout << "Не равен";             
            }

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Нет вывода1";
            ;
        }

    }
    k = 0;
    n = strlen(slovo2);
    for (i=0; i < n-1; i++);
    {
        if (slovo1[i] == a[0])
        {

            k++;
            if (k == 2)
            {

                cout << "Слова - " << slovo2;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Не равен ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Нет вывода";
        }
    }
    k = 0;
    n = strlen(slovo3);
    for (i=0; i < n-1; i++);
    {
        if (slovo1[i] == a[0])
        {

            k++;
                if (k == 2)
                {

                        cout << "Слова - " << slovo3;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Не равен ";
                }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Нет вывода";
        }
    }
    k = 0;
    n = strlen(slovo4);
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++);
    {
        if (slovo1[i] == a[0])
        {

            k++;
            if (k == 2)
            {

                cout << "Слова - " << slovo4;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Не равен ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Нет вывода";
        }
    }
    k = 0;
    n = strlen(slovo5);
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++);
    {

        if (slovo1[i] == a[0])
        {
            k++;
            if (k == 2)
            {

                cout << "Слова - " << slovo5;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Не равен ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Нет вывода";
        }
    }





}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: У вас логическая ошибка, если попалась буква а - то вы ещё не зная сколько раз она попалась - выводите на экран её к-во. Финальное к-во нужно проверять за циклом вычисления колличества, а не внутри, потому что во время расчёта - к-во - непостоянная величина  - которую вы на экране и получаете (и думаете что комп сошел с ума))))).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
char slovo[6][100]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    int r = 0;
    cin >> slovo[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(slovo[i]); ++j) {
        if (slovo[i][j] == 'a')
            ++r;
    }
    if (r == 2)
        cout << slovo[i] << '\n';

}
```

Добавление ваших информационных выводов в циклы, оставляю в качестве упражнения

Comment: Секретный и очень умный  минусующий, не объясните  с чем не согласны?

Comment: Хм, а почему вы сделали массив двумерным? Если он одномерный? 6 это просто обозначение какое по счёту слово

Comment: ПРошу прощения разобрался, но запрещено было делать двумерный массив, но с помощью вашего примера я смог, спасибо большое!

Comment: Двумерный массив  представляет некоторое количество одномерных массивов.   Вам решать что лучше _ объявлять несколько одномерных или один двумерный.